# Derivative chainrule on khanacadamy ignoring some terms

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I watched the chain rule series on khanacademy.org and decided to do the "questions". One of the questions is:

Let $y = \sin(6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2})$

$dy/dx=?$

The answer is $dy/dx=(\cos(6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2}))(12x−4)$

Since

$dy/dx [f(g(x))] = {\rm D}f(g(x))*{\rm D}g(x)$

I figure that it should be

$dy/dx = \cos(6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2})(12x-4-3x^{-2}+10x^{-3})$

Why aren't they deriving the negative exponent terms in the inner function "$g(x)$"?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: wolfram alpha solves it as www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivativ+sin(6x^2−4x−1%2B3x^−1−5x^−2)

Comment: If WA admitted what you had got, therefore they ignored some terms or...

Comment: Babak S. Why would they ignore terms? Are the terms somehow insignificant?

Comment: As it is written above I think they did. No! those terms are depend to $x$ and so they are important.

Comment: My guess is that the author wrote these lines very late, and just forgot to finish the derivation, fell asleep, and next day he sent it to the press as it was.

Comment: You could inform Khanacademy of this error so it won't confuse other students too.

Comment: @Gibarian thanks for the idea. I've submitted an "report an error" to khan academy with an a link to this page.

Comment: @Berci: Perhaps but i somehow have an Deja vu feeling about some negative exponents being ignored like this on the calculus/derivative series on the site. Perhaps the questions are auto generated and the problem could lie in the auto generation...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some error in presenting the solution. That being said, the answer that you have provided is correct. The following is a step-by-step solution for future users.

$$f(x) = \sin(6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2})$$

In order to find the derivative, we must use the chain rule. Therefore: 
$$f'(g(x)) * g'(x)$$ Where $f(x)$ is $\sin(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2}$. Therefore, the solution would be:

$$\begin{align}
\cos (6x^2−4x−1+3x^{−1}−5x^{−2}) * 12x-4+3x^{-2}-5x^{-3}
\end{align}$$

because the derivative of  $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ and derivative of $g(x)$ can be found through the general forumla $\frac{dy}{dx} (x^n) = nx^{n-1}$.